# Как расставить запятые в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Он сразу начал жаловаться (1)что (2)пока он ехал в деревню(3) то он заблудился(4) и ему пришлось переночевать в сторожке.

1 и 3 сомнение не вызывает, там нужна запятая. Трудности возникли с 2 и 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он сразу начал жаловаться, что пока он ехал в деревню, то он заблудился и ему пришлось переночевать в сторожке.

1)ПОКА...ТО - двойной союз, поэтому нет запятой 2.

2) Нет запятой 4, так как союз ЧТО является общим для СПП "пока он ехал в деревню, то он заблудился" и безличного предложения "ему пришлось переночевать в сторожке".

Это сложное синтаксическое целое, старшей конструкцией является СПП с изъяснительной придаточной частью, которая включает СПП с придаточным времени и простое предложение.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял. P.s. это предложения я целиком не помнил - только его конструкцию, поэтому, как я сейчас заметил, 3 раза повторил "он".